# erbの <% %>内で変数を使う場合

Tags: erb, sinatra

erbの`<% %>`内部に変数を数値として使う方法がわかりません。

```
<% <% @@num %>.times do |y| %>
<%= y %>
<% end %>
```

といったかたちを考えているのですが、エラーになります。

本家の[Using erb inside erb at Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342828/using-erb-inside-erb-at-ruby-on-rails)では、

```
<% title "Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %>" %>
```

に対する回答として

```
<% title "Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}" %>
```

が挙げられていたので、`.to_i`を付けて試したのですが、うまく行きませんでした。

この場合、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

追記:
回答ありがとうございます。
教えていただいた方法を試したところ、うまく行きました。

Railsではなく、Sinatraを使用しています（自動でRailsタグがついていたようなので削りました。）。

`#{@@tnum}`の場合

```
"Internal Server Error" "undefined method `join' for #<String:0x5472318>"
```

`<% @@num %>`の場合

```
"Internal Server Error" "undefined method `join' for #<String:0x526cab8>"
```

Comment: 想像で回答しましたが、肝心のエラーの内容が書かれてないので根本的に大外ししているかもしれません。「エラーになります」だけでなくエラーの具体的な内容を追記してください。(回答が正解だったとしても、後から見る人のために)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<% %>`の中はrubyのコード片ですので、その中に`<% %>`が出てくることは普通はありません。rubyのコードとして素直に書けばよいので、

```ruby
<% @@num.times do |y| %>
  <%= y %>
<% end %>
```

となります。

ただし、おそらくこれでも動かないと思います。Railsだと想像しますが、コントローラで`@@num`というクラス変数を定義してもビューでは参照できません。コントローラからビューにデータを受け渡すにはインスタンス変数を使用しますので普通の使い方なら`@num`のはずです。

(追記)sinatraであればクラス変数でも動くようですが、普通の使い方でないのは変わらないので、インスタンス変数を使った方がよいと思います。

Comment: インスタンス変数を使うと、直前の画面で入力した内容は反映されるのですが、その一つ前の画面で入力した内容が飛んでしまいます。  
  クラス変数ではこれがありません。
sinatra解説ページでクラス変数を便利に使っているようだっので、この方法をまねてみました。  
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443718/sinatra-with-a-persistent-variable  
  http://www.ownway.info/Ruby/index.php?sinatra%2Fabout%2Fscope

Comment: そのクラス変数の使い方は非常に危険です。クラス変数は簡単に言えばアプリケーション内で共有されるので、別の人がアクセスしてもそのデータを参照できます。別の質問も拝見しましたが、最低限の基礎知識が不足しているように見受けられます。まずは書籍を購入して一通りのことを勉強されることをおすすめします。